# For loop is stopping at the first letter in string?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, for-loop

This is a rovarspraket function. My for loop is not iterating over the other letters in my phrase. It just stops at 't' which is the first letter in the string. Function is returning 'tot' instead of the full string of 'tothohisos isos fofunon'. I've been staring at this too long. Any suggestions would help. I'm a novice to Javascript by the way.

```
function translate (phrase) {
  var splitPhrase = phrase.split().join();
  var letter = splitPhrase[i];
  var vowels =  ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'];
  var output = '';

  for (i = 0; i < phrase.length; i++) {
    if(vowels.indexOf(letter) === -1) {
      output = letter + 'o' + letter;

  } else {

  }
    return output
}
};

undefined

translate('this is fun')

"tot"
```

Comment: your `return` statement inside loop, also `translate('this is fun')` return `"undefinedoundefined"` for me

Comment: You have a few other issues where `splitPhrase` is not helpful to you (it looks like `"t,h,i,s, ,i.."`), you're not iterating properly (`letter` is not set inside the loop but you want to use it) and the `output` assignment is overwriting the previous value of `output`.

Comment: also `splitPhrase[i];` return _undefined_ because value assigned to `i` only in loop

Comment: Thank you all! I made some simple mistakes that I didn't see. You made it clearer for me to understand.

Answer (score 2):

There are a handful of mistakes or things you may have overlooked in order to reach your final desired result of "tothohisos isos fofunon":

1. You aren't *appending* data to `output`, you're overwriting it.
2. You `return` from within the loop, stopping the loop after the first letter
3. You are using an index `i` before it exists.
4. Unnecessary splitting and joining
5. Not handling the case of when the letter *is* a vowel
6. Not handling spaces

Here's a corrected version:

```js
function translate (phrase) {

    var vowels =  ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', ' ']; // handle spaces
    var output = '';

    for (var i = 0; i < phrase.length; i++) { // use var to declare the index variable
       var letter = phrase[i]; // array notation accesses character in position i
       if (vowels.indexOf(letter) === -1) {
           output += letter + 'o' + letter; // += appends
       } else {
           output += letter; // handle vowels & spaces
       }
    }

    return output; // return outside the loop
};

alert(translate('this is fun'));
```

Comment: :-D your variant return deffers result, OP expect: _full string of 'tothohisos isos fofunon'_

Comment: @Grundy Yeah -- `var dontchange = 'aeiou ';` Or regexp for more control.

Comment: Thanks, I'll fix this to handle the spaces.

Answer (score 1):

As say @Cᴏʀʏ, you have a few issues, more of them inside or around loop, so possibly if avoid using loop directly it would be more clear, like

```js
function translate(phrase) {
  var vowels = {
    'a': true,
    'e': true,
    'i': true,
    'o': true,
    'u': true,
    ' ': true
  };
  
  return phrase.split('').map(function(el){
    return vowels[el] && el || (el+'o'+el);
    }).join('');
}

document.getElementById('r').innerHTML = 'phrase: "'+'this is fun'+'"<br/>';
document.getElementById('r').innerHTML += 'translates: "'+translate('this is fun')+'"<br/>';
```

```html
<div id='r'></div>
```

Variant with regex:

```
"this is fun".replace(/([^aeiou ])/gi, "$1o$1");
```

```js
document.getElementById('r').innerHTML = 'phrase: "'+'this is fun'+'"<br/>';
document.getElementById('r').innerHTML += 'translates: "'+"this is fun".replace(/([^aeiou ])/gi, "$1o$1");+'"<br/>';
```

```html
<div id='r'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a fixed version of Cory's answer. Everything he said was correct except that you also needed to skip when the character is a space as well. In addition there's no reason to waste effort by making the vowels into an array, using a string like below works fine. I've also tested this in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mw3Lxo9b/) to make sure it returns the output you asked for in the original post.

```
function translate (phrase) {
    var skip = 'aeiou ';
    var output = '';

    for (var i = 0; i < phrase.length; i++) {
        var letter = phrase[i];
        if (skip.indexOf(letter) === -1) {
            output += letter + 'o' + letter;
        } else {
            output += letter;
        }
    }

    return output;
};

alert(translate('this is fun'));
```